# How to pause execution on <a> tag?

Tags: php, jquery, html, sweetalert

I have the code

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('company/remove_company/'.$value['id']).'/'.$value['company_name']; ?>" title="Remove Data"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
```

and I have another code written in jquery and using sweetalert function which will popup a warning message if the user are trying to delete record in the database.

```
$(".icon-trash").click(function(){
    swal({
      title: "Are you sure?",
      text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
      type: "warning",
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
      confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
      closeOnConfirm: false }, function() {
        swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
      });
  });
```

the problem of my code is, when the user click on the link, it will popup very fast, and go to the link given in `href` attribute. I would like to prevent it from going to the link, allowing the popup to stay display until the user decide whether to click the `yes delete it` or  `cancel` and will not go to the link if the user click the `cancel`.

Any Help? I don't know what to do about it.

Comment: NEVER EVER have a GET request in an HREF delete data. One visit from Google spider and your data is gone

Comment: use `e.preventDefault()` to on `a` click to stop the execution

Comment: that's why I'm using javascripts or jquery

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I would consider it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent the default action, and upon success, proceed with the location change:

```
$(".icon-trash").click(function(e) {
    var that = this;
    // Prevent the default action.                                      « Look here.
    e.preventDefault();
    swal({
      title: "Are you sure?",
      text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
      type: "warning",
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
      confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
      closeOnConfirm: false }, function() {
        swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
        // In this confirm, add the location.                           « Look here.
        location.href = $(that).attr("href");
      });
  });
```

Also, it is always better not to have any kind of database write functions like:

- Creating a new entry.
- Deleting an entry.

In the `GET` method. It is dangerous. So you should really think of changing it by giving a `POST` method and execute it through JavaScript / AJAX.

Comment: @Fil This is client side, so doesn't matter what you use in the server side. `:)` Edit your OP again with the updated code and let's see if there is any mistake.

Comment: I strongly suggest also to change to `location.href = $(that).data("deleteurl");`

Comment: @mplungjan I don't understand? There's no `data-deleteurl` in the OP right? Do you want the link to be removed from `href`? « Okay, got it.

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks buddy. Added.

Answer (score -1):

you can also achieve this by:

The link:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('company/remove_company/'. $value->id); ?>" class="delete-company">
```

The script:

```
    $('.delete-company').on('click', function(e) {
    var that = $(this);
    swal({   
      title: "Are you sure?",   
      text: "You will not be able to recover this user account!",   
      type: "warning",   
      showCancelButton: true,   
      confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",   
      confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",   
      cancelButtonText: "No, cancel please!",   
      closeOnConfirm: false,   
      closeOnCancel: false 
    }, 
    function(isConfirm){   
      if (isConfirm) { 
       location.replace(that.attr('href'));
       swal("Success","User successfully removed!", "success");
    } else {     
      swal("Cancelled", "Removing user accout was cancelled!", "error");   
    }
   });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

Comment: Add the preventDefault to the top of the function in case of errors in the rest of the function. Also what does your anonymous function do there?